# What word has the most valid meanings, across multiple different languages? (interlingual homographs)

Tags: cross-linguistic, nlp, parts-of-speech, dictionary

What word is valid across the largest number of different languages, and as different part-of-speech?
(The precise term is **interlingual homographs/heteronyms/polysemes**)

Examples:

1. *'rate'* is both verb, noun and adjective in English, so count that as 3. *'rate'* is a [loanword but also a (distinct) noun in German ('instalment')](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/rate), in French: [(noun) 'spleen'](http://fr.thefreedictionary.com/rate) and also as verb (present tense of *'rater'*), and again a loanword in [Norwegian](http://no.thefreedictionary.com/rate). Giving us a **grand total of 3+2+2+1 = 8**.
2. *'baba'* has [meanings across English, French, Spanish, Portuguese, Turkish, as a noun meaning variously: 'rum cake','saliva','father'...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062698/data-structure-for-multi-language-dictionary)
3. *'like'* can be 8 or 9 valid POS in English alone (["What word can fulfill the most parts of speech?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46277/what-word-can-fulfill-the-most-parts-of-speech/67634#67634)), plus [3 in Norwegian](http://no.thefreedictionary.com/like), for a **total of 12**.

Clarifications:

- I am not asking about **homonyms within the same language** (e.g. *'run' or 'set' have >400 meanings in English*). I don't care about straight homonyms, for these purposes that all only boils down to 3 distinct meanings (noun, verb, adjective) for *set*.
- **Ignore capitalization** (e.g. for German nouns)
- **Exclude universal loanwords** like *pizza* (because it's the same word across languages, not a homograph.)
- **Exclude proper nouns** (unless they also have a separate meaning, e.g. 'scotch', 'go dutch'..).
- **Include noun-, adjective- and verb-stemming**
- **Include accents as being significant**, hence *plies*, *pliés* are both valid in English and French.
- **Include colloquial usage, as long as it's common usage.**
- **Words must be 2+ letters** (arbitrarily, to avoid the 'letter 'A' is the name for the letter A, in languages X,Y and Z' definition that Muke quoted. But allowing unusual definitions like *wye* or *cym*, as he cited.

A good multi-lingual dictionary for verifying how many languages a word-spelling is legal in is [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/) or [these others](http://www.dmoz.org/Reference/Dictionaries/World_Languages/Multilingual/).

(**Motivation:** this question arose (legitimately) from a [SO question "Data structure for multi-language dictionary?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062698/data-structure-for-multi-language-dictionary)

**On-topicness:** If anyone quibbles whether this is a [practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), see preceding Motivation remark; also I wanted to ask this on [NLP/CL, but that's sadly closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2761/natural-language-processing-and-computational-linguistics-nlp-cl), and non-English questions are offtopic for [EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com), and this is probably neither on-topic nor well-suited to the general StackOverflow audience. So yes, Computational Linguistics&NLP is on-topic for Linguistics.SE)

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to get a good answer to this, since linguists aren't particularly interested in homographs (other than as a practical concern). But I think it's a legitimate question, since Computational Linguistics questions are on-topic, so +1.

Comment: @arjan: easy to generate all combinations of 2,3,4-letter words (containing at least one vowel from {a,e,i,o,u,y}), then run them through a dictionary(/ies) like Farlex, and sum the count of distinct homographs for distinct POS across multiple languages.

Comment: I think this should be closed as it's not about linguistics. It's about the same sequence of written symbols representing words in the writing systems of many languages. It's not actually about "words" as they're understood in linguistics.

Comment: @Gaston: you're flat wrong, here's citation: [Computational linguistics has subfields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_linguistics#Subfields) about real-world considerations like 'words' as they're found on the internet, aka reality: outside of labeled academic corpora, we can only statistically infer what the person who wrote the word meant, e.g. *rate l'examen* vs *rate my apearance*. Specifially the subfields are **Design of parsers or chunkers for natural languages** and **Design of taggers like POS-taggers (part-of-speech taggers)**

Comment: @Gaston: Uncool. Additionally, I already noted in the question that I had done my homework on every single StackExchange network site that might suit this question: NLP/CL is dead, non-English is offtopic on EL&U, and this is too specialist for SO. So, according to you there is no SE site whatsoever where I may ask this question?

Comment: @Gaston: you have never heard of **Natural Language Processing** ? Things like the technology behind Apple's Siri are not a part of linguistics? Can I stop now?

Comment: @smci I'm not sure what your comments have to do with your question. Perhaps you're saying that your interest is in the problem of identifying a language given a single written word, where that word may be found with identical orthographic form in many languages?

Comment: @smci This question is kind of asking for a list... Perhaps you could follow Gaston's suggestions and reword it? **Don't reply here** when you're rewording it. Please open a question in our [Meta]. We'll help you there.

Comment: @Alenanno: no it's not asking for a list. The title and first line clearly and unambiguously state it's asking for a single word. That's why they ask **What word?**

Comment: @smci Ok but how are we supposed to find that? Are you asking for studies being done on this, or you want us to "guess the word"?

Comment: @Alenanno: either from knowledge about POS (such as the taxonomy I cited of the English word *like*) and interlingual homographs/polysemes, or computational linguistics. Citations works, guesses work too. I do not believe there is much or any literature in this (for the same reasons people do not seem to build multi-language dictionaries, per my question I cite at the end).

Comment: No, let's exclude guesses. Guesses mean lots of answers, little content. So make it clear in your question.

Comment: My first instinctive reaction was like Gaston, that this isn't a linguistics question and I was going to vote it down. But on reading the comments I actually agree with arjan that it is something that comes up in computational linguistics. In fact I've personally come up against the homograph problem when playing with machine translation and also when trying to come up with good basic structure of the English Wiktionary when it was much younger. So the cross-language-homograph problem is a real topic, but I'm not convinced the "word with most meanings" is a good question.

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, that's part of my objection. Treating this as being about one 'word', and even worse, saying it's about polysemy, is misleading. And surely it's asking for one word-form and a list of languages where it occurs?

Comment: @hippietrail No-one yet has explained how this issue of 'a string of symbols that is identical across multiple languages' is relevant to linguistics. Within individual languages it is the issue of orthography; but when comparing word forms across languages it is divorced from linguistics.

Comment: Hmm yes it could be that it's a computing problem but not really a linguistics problem at all - even computational linguistics. And the number shouldn't be relevant to solving the OPs problem. Whatever they're trying to achieve shouldn't involve some fixed constant.

Comment: I've voted to close. Awareness of orthographic homographs across languages is related to computational linguistics but which orthographic word has the most homographs is very unlikely to have an objective definite answer and is at best a factoid. Build your software around the assumption that "many orthographic words have various homographs within a language and in other languages". Knowing the answer might be "on" or "da" or whatever won't change anything.

Comment: I've decided to close the question **for now**, at least until we fix it. @smci Remember that [closing a question is not forever](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/248/111), so show your interest and help us to help you to fix it (assuming it can be done). I suggest you post a question in our [Meta]. You have enough reputation to do so. :)

Answer (score 3):

I choose /ki/, which is a noun class prefix in a good hundred Bantu languages. It also means "key" in English, "key" in Langalanga, "who" in French, "give" in Ngwe.

Comment: /ki/ means "who" in italian as well, and "tree" in Japanese. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's interesting enough to try to lay out a method that one might use to try to answer this question, and I think the question is more interesting as one about words written in a basic / lossy IPA (such as how we tended to use [Kirshenbaum](http://www.kirshenbaum.net/IPA/) on Usenet) rather than the languages' respective orthographies.

If I had the relevant tools available, I'd try this:

- Two-sound CV combinations should probably win out.
- Look for two-sound Austronesian words. There are over 800 Austronesian languages, and many Malayo-Polynesian of them can be quite close.
- There are 250-500 Bantu languages, and they can be quite close as well, so if bare prefixes are allowed (and also even if they aren't), jlovegren's suggestion of /ki/ should be taken quite seriously, especially since both the consonant and the vowel are extremely prevalent worldwide.
- It's important to note that along with importation of the Roman alphabet we get at least 20-30 loanwords for names of letters into each language. This applies to the hundreds, possibly thousands of languages that "use" the Roman alphabet to some capacity.
- Languages using scripts in the Brahmic tradition tend to name consonants with a trailing schwa. /kə/, for example. Whether this vowel is involved in many words in other languages seems to rely heavily on how we're transcribing.

My guess (heavily influenced by how Malayo-Polynesian languages tend to pronounce the alphabet) is we would end up getting /ka/, /ke/, /ki/, /nu/, /pe/, /pi/, /te/, or /ti/.

Another question: For each length n, what is the most popular n-letter (in IPA) word? For n at least 4, I have no idea what one could do short of crawling a massive database.

Edit: Just noticed that we're supposed to exclude universal loanwords, so I'll rework my answer soon or take it down.